# apache + lighttpd on debian, the both should use ssl, port 443 already used

Tags: apache, ssl, lighttpd

I installed apache and lighttpd in debian 7, apache used port 80 and lighttpd 88, now I install ssl for apache and when i tried to do the same for lighttpd, I got error because 443 is already used by apache.

how can I have the both ssl working? without to disable apache ssl. 
can I just use another port for lighttpd? are there ports just for https?

Comment: I think this would be better asked on http://serverfault.com as it's not related to programming at all - and server configurations etc... are probably better there

Comment: ok, I will ask there.